# How to keep track of combination changes in checkbox group

Tags: jquery

How can I keep track of combination checks or un checks to get following result?

```
    If A Only  -----> phaseVal = "2,0"
    If B Only  -----> phaseVal = "3,0"
    If C Only  -----> phaseVal = "1,0"  
    If AB  ---------> phaseVal = "3,4,5,0" 
    If AC  ---------> phaseVal = "6,4,2,,0" 
    If BC  ---------> phaseVal = "1,0" 
    If ABC ---------> phaseVal = "7,6,5,4,3,0"
```

```js
var phaseVal ="";
$('input:checkbox[name=phase]').on('change', function() {
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="phase" value="" />A <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="phase" value="" />B<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="phase" value="" />C<br />
```

Comment: There is no trick. You need to iterate through the checkboxes and use separate checks to assign the value to `phaseVal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var phaseVal ="";
$('input:checkbox[name=phase]').on('change', function() {
var str = 'input:checkbox[name=phase]:checked[value="';
  if($(str+'A"]').length*$(str+'B"]').length) console.log('A and B selected');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="phase" value="A" />A <br />
<input type="checkbox" name="phase" value="B" />B<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="phase" value="C" />C<br />
```

You want to change the value to this letters